# data.table: How do I pass a character vector to a function get data.table to treat its contents as column names?

Tags: r, function, data.table

Here is a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(airquality)
```

This example produces the output I want:

```
DT[, `:=`(New_Ozone= log(Ozone), New_Wind=log(Wind))]
```

How can I write a function `log_those_columns` such that the following code snippet outputs the same result?

```
old_names <- c("Ozone", "Wind")
new_names <- c("New_Ozone", "New_Wind")
log_those_columns(DT, old_names, new_names)
```

Note that I need `old_names` and `new_names` to be flexible enough to contain any number of columns.

(I see from the similar StackOverflow questions on this topic that the answer probably involves some combination of `.SD`, `with=F`, `parse()`, `eval()`, and/or `substitute()`, but I can't seem to nail which of those to use and where).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picking up [MichaelChirico's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232260/r-data-table-how-do-i-pass-a-character-vector-to-a-function-get-data-table-to-t#comment104677773_59232369), the function definition can be written as:

```
log_those_columns <- function(DT, cols_in, cols_new) {
  DT[, (cols_new) := lapply(.SD, log), .SDcols = cols_in]
}
```

which returns:

```
log_those_columns(DT, old_names, new_names)
DT
```

> ```
>      Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day New_Ozone New_Wind
>   1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1  3.713572 2.001480
>   2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2  3.583519 2.079442
>   3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3  2.484907 2.533697
>   4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4  2.890372 2.442347
>   5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        NA 2.660260
>  ---                                                     
> 149:    30     193  6.9   70     9  26  3.401197 1.931521
> 150:    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27        NA 2.580217
> 151:    14     191 14.3   75     9  28  2.639057 2.660260
> 152:    18     131  8.0   76     9  29  2.890372 2.079442
> 153:    20     223 11.5   68     9  30  2.995732 2.442347
> ```

as expected.

#### A more flexible approach

The function used to transform the data can be passed as a parameter as well:

```
fct_those_columns <- function(DT, cols_in, cols_new, fct) {
  DT[, (cols_new) := lapply(.SD, fct), .SDcols = cols_in]
}
```

The call:

```
fct_those_columns(DT, old_names, new_names, log)
head(DT)
```

works as expected:

> ```
>    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day New_Ozone New_Wind
> 1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1  3.713572 2.001480
> 2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2  3.583519 2.079442
> 3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3  2.484907 2.533697
> 4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4  2.890372 2.442347
> 5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        NA 2.660260
> 6:    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6  3.332205 2.701361
> ```

The function name can be passed as character:

```
fct_those_columns(DT, old_names, new_names, "sqrt")
head(DT)
```

> ```
>    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day New_Ozone New_Wind
> 1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1  6.403124 2.720294
> 2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2  6.000000 2.828427
> 3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3  3.464102 3.549648
> 4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4  4.242641 3.391165
> 5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        NA 3.781534
> 6:    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6  5.291503 3.860052
> ```

or as an anonymous function:

```
fct_those_columns(DT, old_names, new_names, function(x) x^(1/2))
head(DT)
```

> ```
>    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day New_Ozone New_Wind
> 1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1  6.403124 2.720294
> 2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2  6.000000 2.828427
> 3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3  3.464102 3.549648
> 4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4  4.242641 3.391165
> 5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        NA 3.781534
> 6:    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6  5.291503 3.860052
> ```

#### An even more flexible approach

The function below derives the names of the new columns by prepending the names of the input columns with the name of the function automatically:

```
fct_those_columns <- function(DT, cols_in, fct) {
  fct_name <- substitute(fct)
  cols_new <- paste(if (class(fct_name) == "name") fct_name else fct_name[3], cols_in, sep = "_")
  DT[, (cols_new) := lapply(.SD, fct), .SDcols = cols_in]
}

DT <- data.table(airquality)
fct_those_columns(DT, old_names, sqrt)
fct_those_columns(DT, old_names, data.table::as.IDate)
fct_those_columns(DT, old_names, function(x) x^(1/2))
DT
```

> ```
>      Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day sqrt_Ozone sqrt_Wind as.IDate_Ozone as.IDate_Wind x^(1/2)_Ozone x^(1/2)_Wind
>   1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1   6.403124  2.720294     1970-02-11    1970-01-08      6.403124     2.720294
>   2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2   6.000000  2.828427     1970-02-06    1970-01-09      6.000000     2.828427
>   3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3   3.464102  3.549648     1970-01-13    1970-01-13      3.464102     3.549648
>   4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4   4.242641  3.391165     1970-01-19    1970-01-12      4.242641     3.391165
>   5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5         NA  3.781534           <NA>    1970-01-15            NA     3.781534
>  ---                                                                                                               
> 149:    30     193  6.9   70     9  26   5.477226  2.626785     1970-01-31    1970-01-07      5.477226     2.626785
> 150:    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27         NA  3.633180           <NA>    1970-01-14            NA     3.633180
> 151:    14     191 14.3   75     9  28   3.741657  3.781534     1970-01-15    1970-01-15      3.741657     3.781534
> 152:    18     131  8.0   76     9  29   4.242641  2.828427     1970-01-19    1970-01-09      4.242641     2.828427
> 153:    20     223 11.5   68     9  30   4.472136  3.391165     1970-01-21    1970-01-12      4.472136     3.391165
> ```

Note that `x^(1/2)_Ozone` is not a syntactically valid name in R and needs to be put in backquotes:

```
DT$`x^(1/2)_Ozone`
```

Answer (score 1):

you only need to write a function:

```
log_those_columns <- function(D,old_names,new_names) 
DT[,(new_names) := lapply(mget(old_names),log)]
log_those_columns(DT,old_names,new_names)
DT
     Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day New_Ozone New_Wind
  1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1  3.713572 2.001480
  2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2  3.583519 2.079442
  3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3  2.484907 2.533697
  4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4  2.890372 2.442347
  5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        NA 2.660260
 ---
```

Comment: I would use .SDcols, not mget, here