# Function in data.table with two columns as arguments

Tags: r, function, input, data.table, multiple-columns

I have the following function:

```
DT <- data.table(col1 = 1:4, col2 = c(2:5))

fun <- function(DT, fct){
  DT_out <- DT[,new_col := fct]
  return(DT_out)
}

fun(input, fct = function(x = col1, y = col2){y - x})
```

In reality I have some processing before and after this code snippet, thus I do not wish to use directly the statement `DT[,new_col := fct]` with a fixed `fct` (because the `fct` should be flexible). I know this question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232260/data-table-how-do-i-pass-a-character-vector-to-a-function-get-data-table-to-tre) one, but I cannot figure out how to reformulate the code such that two columns as arguments for the function are allowed. The code above gives the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(new_col, fct)) : 
  RHS of assignment is not NULL, not an an atomic vector (see ?is.atomic) and not a list column.
```

Comment: Do you want `new_col := fct(col1,col2)`? As it is, you're assigning a function to `new_col`, not it's output

Comment: No that won't satisfy my needs, because I want the arguments to be flexible like in the answer given below! But thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option if you don't mind adding quotes around the variable names

```
fun <- function(DT, fun, ...){
  fun_args <- c(...)
  DT[,new_col := do.call(fun, setNames(mget(fun_args), names(fun_args)))]
}

fun(DT, fun = function(x, y){y - x}, x = 'col1', y = 'col2')

DT
#    col1 col2 new_col
# 1:    1    2       1
# 2:    2    3       1
# 3:    3    4       1
# 4:    4    5       1
```

Or use `.SDcols` (same result as above)

```
fun <- function(DT, fun, ...){
  fun_args <- c(...)
  DT[, new_col := do.call(fun, setNames(.SD, names(fun_args))), 
     .SDcols = fun_args]
}
```

Comment: Yesss! Both are nice solutions, but I like the second one with `.SDcols` better. It is clearer and more in the style of `data.table` in my opinion. And thanks a lot for pointing out the three-dots construct, this opens a whole new world for me!